# Heights and circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-transformation

In a triangle $ABC$ the heights $BB'$ and $CC'$ intersect the circumcircle of $ABC$ at $E$ and $F$. Prove that $\displaystyle B'C'=\frac{EF}{2}$.

The circle of diameter $BC$ passes through $B'$ and $C'$ since $BB'C=CC'B=90^{\circ}$. $EFC=\frac{\stackrel{\frown}{EC}}{2}=B'BC=CC'B$ then the lines $B'C'$ and $EF$ are parallel. They are also parallel to the tangent at $A$. How to continue?

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of $ABC$. It is well know (and easy to prove) that reflection of $H$ across $B'$ and $C'$ is respectively $E$ and $F$. So $B'C'$ is a middle line in triangle $HEF$ parallel to $EF$, so $B'C' =EF/2$.

Comment: If  $B'$ is the midpoint of the segment $HE$, it's easy to proceed. My question is why is $B'$ the midpoint of $HE$?

Comment: $AHB' \cong AEB'$ (asa)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let 
$\angle CAB=\alpha$,
$\angle ABC=\beta$,
$\angle BCA=\gamma$.

\begin{align} 
\angle ABE&=\angle FBA=90^\circ-\alpha
,\\
\angle FBE&=180^\circ-2\alpha
,\\
\triangle BB_1C_1:\quad
\frac{|B_1C_1|}{\sin\angle C_1BB_1}
&=\frac{|BC_1|}{\sin\angle BB_1C_1}
,\\
\frac{|B_1C_1|}{\cos\alpha}
&=\frac{|BC|\cos\beta}{\cos\beta}
,\\
|B_1C_1|&=|BC|\cos\alpha
,\\
\triangle BEF:\quad
\frac{|EF|}{\sin2\alpha}
&=
\frac{|BF|}{\cos\beta}
=
\frac{|BC|\cos\beta/\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}
=
\frac{|BC|}{\sin\alpha}
,\\
|EF|&
=\frac{|BC|\sin2\alpha}{\sin\alpha}
=\frac{2|BC|\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}
=2|BC|\cos\alpha
,\\
|EF|&=2|B_1C_1|
.
\end{align}